# Custom project-level templates for angular components generated via angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-cli, angular-schematics

How do I add custom angular component schematics to existing project?

I would like to have e.g. `my-page` component templates that will replicate existing `\node_modules\@schematics\angular\component\` files but with edited templates.

I expect it to be achievable through `angular-cli` e.g. `ng g my-page pagename` command with schematics attribute.

Currently I modified code for existing angular's schematics under `\node_modules\` so this works fine for me (until next package installation) but I would like to share this with the team so everyone will use predefined templates that will be stored in e.g. `src\team-schematics\`.

How do I achieve this?

I tried to create new schematic via `schematics schematic --name my-schematic`, copied angular schematic into `\ClientApp\src\app\my-schematic\\` and trying to launch `$ ng generate my-page --collection \ClientApp\src\app\my-schematic` but no luck as of now:

`Error: Could not find module "\\ClientApp\\src\\app\\my-schematic\\" from "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Projects\\yyy`

Comment: I follow this https://medium.com/rocket-fuel/angular-schematics-simple-schematic-76be2aa72850. After you has the schematic don't forget build it: **npm run build**, and in the directory of your new app make a **npm link path-too-your-schematic**, then You can do the **ng g simple-schematic:simple-schematic --name="some name"**. NOTE: I need to make **npm install** before build the schematic

Comment: IMO @Eliseo 's comment should be accepted answer.

Comment: @Eliseo following that article I am getting an error `Cannot find schematic X in collection X-collection`

Comment: I download the github: https://github.com/jonbcampos/schematics and work for me (Angular 7). I don't know what can happens, by the way check packgaje.json and collection.json

Comment: I created a custom schematic named schematics and if I wanna generate it with `ng g schematics:schematics --name my-name` it doesn’t generate anything.

Comment: Maybe this guide can help you: https://indepth.dev/posts/1438/extend-angular-schematics-to-customize-your-development-process

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't modify core schematics. On the other hand, you can create your own schematic.

Creating the schematic is a step-by-step process. You can find the same at [Schematics — An Introduction](https://blog.angular.io/schematics-an-introduction-dc1dfbc2a2b2).

Comment: Whoever downvoted my post, thanks for your time and vote. It would be really great if you can add a comment about how can I improve my answer.

Comment: I didn't, but I'd imagine it's twofold: 1. your answer is basically just the link, but you should have _something_ more so it's not just a redirect (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). And 2. that link is about generating a new schematic project, not adding one within an existing project.

Answer (score -1):

As for as Angular CLI we can only have one Schematics. Might be you can create custom schmatics '@foo/schematics' and extends the @angular/schematics in angular.json and customize the schematics based on your needs.

```
ng new C myComponent --collection=@foo/schematics
```